# Preferred way of lazily loading responsive images in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there a preferred way for lazily loading images in a Shopify theme? I've been looking through various themes and they all seem to be doing the same thing a little bit differently.

For example, the the default Dawn theme does the following

```
<img
        srcset="{%- if section.settings.image.width >= 375 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '375x' }} 375w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if block.settings.image.width >= 550 -%}{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '550x' }} 550w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 750 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '750x' }} 750w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1100 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1100x' }} 1100w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1500 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1500x' }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1780 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1780x' }} 1780w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 2000 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '2000x' }} 2000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 3000 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '3000x' }} 3000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 3840 -%}{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '3840x' }} 3840w,{%- endif -%}
          {{ section.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }} {{ section.settings.image.width }}w"
        sizes="{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile %}(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw{% elsif section.settings.image_2 != blank %}50vw{% else %}100vw{% endif %}"
        src="{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1500x' }}"
        loading="lazy"
        alt="{{ section.settings.image.alt | escape }}"
        width="{{ section.settings.image.width }}"
        height="{{ section.settings.image.width | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio }}"
        {% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %}class="banner__media-image-half"{% endif %}
      >
```

While other themes sometimes do the following while leveraging the lazysizes JS library

```
    {% assign img_url = block.settings.image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' %}
    <img class="image-content__image lazyload"
         src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x300' }}"
         data-src="{{ img_url }}"
         data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 1944, 2048]"
         data-aspectratio="{{ block.settings.image.aspect_ratio }}"
         data-sizes="auto"
         alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt | escape }}">
```

or

```
<img class="slideshow__image slideshow__image--{{ block.id }} lazyload"
  src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }}"
  data-src="{{ img_url }}"
  data-widths="[540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 1944, 2048]"
  data-aspectratio="{{ block.settings.image.aspect_ratio }}"
  data-sizes="auto"
  data-parent-fit="cover"
  alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt | escape }}">
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The world is thankfully moving away from using JS libraries to lazyload images now that `loading="lazy"` is more openly supported.

There's very little reason to continue using JS lazyloading libraries now.

That being said, if it's already baked into a theme, without replacing it all, it's likely easier to stick with it.